# just(recently) + present perfect or simple past

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I heard many people saying "he just left the room", but I read that just(recently) is used with present perfect. So are people just omitting **has**?

Comment: "I read that just(recently) is used with present perfect" - that's not correct.  You can certainly use it with the simple past too.

Answer (score 2):

He just left the room.

He has just left the room.

Both the sentences are grammatical, without any difference in meaning.

The adverb just means very recently. In BrE, the usage of the present perfect for recent actions is dominant, whereas in AmE, the past simple and the present perfect are equally used.

Comment: The difference between the two tenses is that the simple past is for finished action and the present perfect is for unfinished actions or states or habits that started in the past and continue to the present. Would the following examples be correct way to distinguish the two tenses? **John just left the room. He will be back in two hours.** ***John has just left the room, but he'll be back because he forgot his car key.***

Can you give some examples to distinguish the use of simple past vs present perfect tense for a recent action?

Answer (score 2):

In short, both are grammatically correct.

---

Other answers are informative and very helpful. I'm just adding a figure.

[image]

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He%20just%20left%2CHe%20has%20just%20left&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CHe%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHe%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CHe%20has%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20has%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHe%20has%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2CHe%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHe%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CHe%20has%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhe%20has%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHe%20has%20just%20left%3B%2Cc0) shows that the past simple version is more commonly used than the present perfect version.

Answer (score 1):

You may say either.

> He just left the room / He has just left the room.
>
> She just ironed that shirt. / She has just ironed that shirt.

There is no real difference between these two forms.  I expect there are some people who prefer one over the other, but both are natural English.

Answer (score 0):

Just is used to express recently completed action in both tenses.

1. Just with present perfect tense, to mean "a very short time ago"
   Example: He has just left the room.
2. Just with past tense is also to mean, "a very short time ago"
   Example: He just left the room

Note: In British English "just" is often used with the present perfect, however, in American English the simple past is often used with it.

Comment: "a short time ago" is a single moment in time. It has no duration, so you can't say "during a very short time ago". "English" should always be capitalised.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar of the two sentences is different, but you can't see it because the verb form is "left" in both cases. Let's use the verb "to eat" instead.

> He just **ate** a sandwich.
>
> He **was** just **eating** a sandwich.
>
> He **has** just **eaten** a sandwich.
>
> He **has** just **been eating** a sandwich.
>
> He **had** just **eaten** a sandwich when ...
>
> He **had** just **been eating** a sandwich when ...

You can used "just" with any past tense (including the present perfect) with the meaning of "shortly before". The present perfect actually describes something that happened in the past, but is finished in the present.

In the present tense and future tense "just" means "only":

> He just **eats** a sandwich.
>
> He **is** just **eating** a sandwich.
>
> He **will** just **eat** a sandwich.
>
> He **will** just **be eating** a sandwich.